# How do I mimic the route handling?

Tags: 8, routes

In drupal 7 I have a chunk of code that gets the page content by mimicking what drupal does:

```
$router_item = menu_get_item($href);
if ($router_item['access']) {
  if ($router_item['include_file']) {
    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $router_item['include_file'];
  }
  $page_callback_result = call_user_func_array($router_item['page_callback'], $router_item['page_arguments']);
}
```

$page_callback_result will then hold the HMTL of the content region of that page.

I'm trying to port this to drupal 8 but I'm stuck. Anyone has a clue how to do this?
I'm close, but I'm struggling on getting the controller:

```
 $request = Request::create('/' . $href);
 $controller_resolver = \Drupal::getContainer()->get('controller_resolver');
 //$controller = $controller_resolver->getController($request);
 $callable = $controller_resolver->getControllerFromDefinition('\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage');
 $arguments = $controller_resolver->getArguments($request, $callable);
 $page_content = call_user_func_array($callable, $arguments);
```

The problem is that $controller = $controller_resolver->getController($request); returns FALSE. I'm trying to get the proper controller for a request, for some reason this won't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the purpose of this, now in Drupal 8 Guzzle is available to creating external and internal request.

```
$this->httpClient->get($href)->getBody(TRUE);
```

The httpClient is a service in Drupal 8  api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/http_client/8

you need inject this service in your class.

if you need read the Route properties like callback, permissions, etc. you need use the routeProvider service.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21RouteProvider.php/class/RouteProvider/8

maybe more information about that problem help us to understand what is the best way to porting for Drupal 8

UPDATE:

Thinking a little more, you want to make a sub-request?

something like https://gist.github.com/dmouse/4976461875a27689d155

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what I need! I'll try this out tonigh, thanks!

Comment: Your code gets me the HTML of the body, but this isn't really what I need. I just need the HTML of the content of that page. In other words I have to mimic the following code that drupal executes in core:
`$response = call_user_func_array($controller, $arguments);` As you see in my code example above I'm trying to get the controller and the arguments, but for some reason they are both NULL

Comment: @Robin Why not put some debug code in to inspect the `$request` for a normal page, that seems like the easiest way to find out what your own `$request` is missing?

Comment: @Clive, My request object is ok, it is this line of code that causes trouble: `$controller = $controller_resolver->getController($request)`

Comment: That's my point - `$request->attributes->get('_controller')` is obviously empty, when it shouldn't be (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Controller%21ControllerResolver.php/function/ControllerResolver%3A%3AgetController/8). Check your log - you'll have an error message like this: _"Unable to look for the controller as the "_controller" parameter is missing"_

Comment: Nothing in my log. When `$request->attributes->get('_controller')` is empty, the function just returns FALSE. Just have to find out WHY it returns false

Comment: It returns false _because_ `$request->attributes->get('_controller')` is empty. Which can only mean your `$request` is not what it should be

Comment: Be careful because drupal uses two indexes "_controller" and "_content". to call a controller. the correct way would $sub_request = Request::create('/search/node', 'GET',['keys'=>'node']);